# Search of interval optimization

Tags: python, optimization, micro-optimization

My goal is to find the probability density function for a certain distribution, using a given algorithm.

This algorithm requires that I search in which interval a float is placed in. Even though the code runs perfectly, it takes too long. I was looking for a way of optimizing my code, but none came to mind.

In each iteration I check if the float is in the interval: if that's the case, I'd like to had a unity to   the position I'm considering, in array p.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import random as rd

n = [10,100,1000]
N = [10**6]
dy = 0.005
k_max = int(1/dy-1)
y = np.array([(j+0.5)*dy for j in range(k_max+1)])
intervals = np.linspace(0,1,k_max+2)

def p(y,n,N):

   p = np.zeros(len(y))

   Y = np.array([sum(np.array([rd.random() for k in range(n)]))/n for j in range(N)])
   z = np.array([sum(np.array([rd.random() for k in range(n)])) for l in range(N)])

   for j in Y:
       for i in range(len(y)-1):
           if intervals[i] <= j < intervals[i+1]:
               p[i] += 1

   return(p/(dy*N))

for a in n:
    pi = p(y,a,N[0])

    plt.plot(y,pi,label = 'n = ' + str(a))

plt.title('Probability Density Function')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('p(x)')
plt.show()
```

**Edit:** I've added the full code, as requested.
**Edit 2:** Fixed an error intervals.

Comment: What is `rd`? If you're using it to create `Y` and `z` randomly, use `numpy`'s built in functions.

Comment: @Deep my bad! I'll had the rest of the code

Comment: The call of the function is missing.

Comment: @Armali the call is not important. It returns what it is supposed to return. Only this fraction is not optimized.

Comment: Then getting help also seems not important to you.

Comment: @Armali I've made it available, as requested!

Comment: I'd really like to run the code and see what I can do, but `for n in N:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.

Comment: Have you considered using an Interval Tree data structure? It can be useful if a number of intervals is too big: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interval-tree/

Comment: @Armali I apologize. I had carelessly copied the incorrect code. It should be correct now!

Comment: @Olha Thanks, I'll take a look into it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and simple optimization can be made here:

```
   for j in Y:
       for i in range(len(y)-1):
           if intervals[i] <= j < intervals[i+1]:
               p[i] += 1
```

Since `intervals` consists of `len(y)` evenly spaced numbers over the interval [0, 1], which is also the range of `Y` values, we need not search the position of `j` in `intervals`, but rather we can compute it.

```
    for j in Y: p[int(j*(len(y)-1))] += 1
```

Also we can remove the unused

```
   z = np.array([sum(np.array([rd.random() for k in range(n)])) for l in range(N)])
```

The greatest part of the remaining execution time is taken by

```
   Y = np.array([sum(np.array([rd.random() for k in range(n)]))/n for j in range(N)])
```

Here the inner conversions to `np.array` are very time consuming; better leave them all out:

```
   Y = [sum([rd.random() for k in range(n)])/n for j in range(N)]
```

Comment: It seems to break for simple example. Let $\Delta y = 0.5$. Then $k_{max} = 1}$ and y would have len = 2. Imagine Y  = [0.4,0.8], then we should have p = [1,1]. However, int(j*(len(y)-1)) yields 0 for both cases!

Comment: On that note, I have fixed my code, which did not divide the intervals by the right amount.

Comment: Regarding your _simple example_: Right, and that is equal to what the original loops yield, which the optimization exactly reproduces. If that's broken, it was broken from the start.

Comment: Even tought it breaks, I think I have now a better idea on how to tackle the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: But why do you think it's broken? The `intervals` for k_max = 1 is `array([0., 1.])`, so index  _0 for both cases_ is correct, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, yes! But that was my mistake. I should've created an array intervals = [0,0.5,1].